# Breakpoints with a simple condition in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I've got a simple breakpoint condition which should yield a boolean value but Eclipse thinks the return type of the expression is void :-/

axis.getTransaction().getStructuralNode().getKind() == ENodes.TEXT_KIND && axis.getTransaction().getValueOfCurrentNode().equals("var:7")

The first part checks for equal enum values, the second compares a String. And I've used it in a simple Logger statement, so it really returns true or false everytime. Maybe it's because I'm not using a "final" eclipse build, but some nightly version or so, because I'm using Java7. I'm not sure if the new builds of Eclipse now have Java7 support.

best regards,

Johannes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a return statement?

```
return axis.getTransaction().getStructuralNode().getKind() == ENodes.TEXT_KIND && axis.getTransaction().getValueOfCurrentNode().equals("var:7");
```